# PFC required in China?

Tags: power-factor-correction

Is Power Factor Correction required in China?  I am designing a high power, >3kW power supply and need to know to what power factor it needs to meet.

Comment: If you are going to concern yourself with whether your supply complies with Chinese regulations, you should worry about *all* of them, and probably try to get a copy.

Comment: Put a China Export "CE" mark on it and you can skip all regulations.

Comment: The best way would be to use a regulatory consultant that covers china. In the past when I need to see what specs products need to conform to, I look at other products in the same category and look at the manual or the product page. Then look for the standards, this is the cheap way of doing it and does not always work.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the Chinese mandatory national standards are based on similar IEC (European) standards. In this case, probably  [EN 61000-3-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_61000-3-2).

A comparison of these standards (Chinese vs. foreign)  related to your question can be found in [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.845.8276&rep=rep1&type=pdf) interesting Masters thesis "Comparison of Chinese and International Harmonic, Interharmonic and Flicker Standards by Yao Wang."

But you'd be best to purchase the actual standards if you want to have your product eventually tested for conformity.

Comment: Spehro,  Thank you for the information and the thesis.  I assume the Chinese requlations are similar but am investigating why there are significant cost differences in products I am comparing and was wondering if PFC was left out.

Comment: Export products don't need to conform to their domestic standards, of course, and the domestic standards may be unevenly enforced at that.